# How to copy the XPO files out of version control...partial code working, bizarre issue

Tags: version-control, axapta, dynamics-ax-2009, x++

I began upgrading our layers to Roll Up 7 while we still were developing in another environment with TFS turned on.  We were at say version 1850, and by the time I finished, we were at 1900.  So the goal is to merge in the 50 different check-ins into the completed RU7 environment.  Each check-in can contain many different objects, and each object is stored in TFS as an XPO somewhere.

My code is 90% of the way there, but the issue arrises when copying the files out of the temp directory.  When I look in the temp directory, the files aren't there, but somehow they're able to be accessed.

```
static void Job33(Args _args)
{
    #File
    SysVersionControlSystem sysVersionControlSystem = versioncontrol.parmSysVersionControlSystem();
    SysVersionControlTmpItem    contents;
    SysVersionControlTmpChange  change;
    SysVersionControlTmpChange  changes;
    int i;
    SysVersionControlTmpItem contentsAddition;
    SysVersionControlTmpItem contentsItem;
    str                         writePath;
    Set       permissionSet = new Set(Types::Class);
    str                         fileName;
    int                         n;
    ;

    change = versioncontrol.getChangesHistory();

    // BP deviation documented
    changes.setTmp();
    changes.checkRecord(false);
    changes.setTmpData(change);

    while select changes
        order by changes.ChangeNumber asc
        where changes.ChangeNumber > 1850
    {
        writePath = @'C:\TEMP\' + int2str(changes.ChangeNumber) + @'\';

        contentsAddition = versioncontrol.getChangeNumberContents(changes.ChangeNumber);

        n = 0;
        while select contentsAddition
        {
            // HOW DOES THIS LINE ACCESS THE FILE BUT MY METHOD CAN NOT??
            contentsAddition.viewFile();
            //?????????????


            // Write to appropriate directory
            if(!WinAPI::pathExists(writePath))
                WinAPI::createDirectory(writePath);

            n++;

            fileName = int2str(changes.ChangeNumber) + '_' + int2str(n) + '.xpo';

            if (WinAPI::fileExists(contentsAddition.fileName(), false))
            {
                // Write to appropriate directory
                if(!WinAPI::pathExists(writePath))
                    WinAPI::createDirectory(writePath);

                WinAPI::copyFile(contentsAddition.fileName(), writePath + fileName, true);
                info(strfmt("|%1|%2|", contentsAddition.fileName(), writePath + fileName));
            }
        }

        info(strfmt("%1", changes.ChangeNumber));
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this not dangerous? what if you overwrite a change/fix from roll up 7?

Comment: We had our RU1 environment that we were upgrading to RU7.  We turned on version control and then I began upgrading to RU7 in a static environment while developers wrote code in the RU1 environment with VC on.  I completed 2 weeks later, and now I'm exporting out all of the code modifications in the RU1 environment to merge into the RU7 environment if that makes sense.  This way we don't have to be on a code freeze during the upgrade :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buried in Classes\SysVersionControlFilebasedBackEndTfs there is a .Net assembly that is used.  I was able to use this to extract what I needed mixed in with the upper code.  After I used this...my code from above started working strangely enough??

Somehow there was a file lock on the folder that I copied TO, that just wouldn't let me delete it until I closed AX...no big deal, but it suggests there is a tfsProxy.close() method or something I should have called.

```
Microsoft.Dynamics.Morphx.TeamFoundationServer.Proxy tfsProxy = new Microsoft.Dynamics.Morphx.TeamFoundationServer.Proxy();
;

tfsProxy.DownloadFile(contentsAddition.InternalFilename, changes.ChangeNumber, writePath + fileName);
```

Answer (score 0):

So you are trying to just get the objects that were changed so you can import them into the new RU7 environment? Why not do this within Visual Studio directly? You can pull the XPOs from there based on the history of changesets since you started the RU7 upgrade.

Also, you should use branching for this. It would have been easy to just branch the new code in that way. Something you should look into for the future.

Comment: I don't have access to VS.  Some weird SOX rules we have.  I think I just stumbled across your blog about DAXMusings about TFS.  Seems like an interesting concept I should probably learn, especially for 2012.  My code was just a quick & dirty to dump out the XPOs.  What you're suggesting looks like a more advanced concept that makes sense for repeating this sort of project.  I'll look into it for sure.